# Running Client Code on Nodejs in Sandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine

I want clients to be able to send scripts that will be ran on the server. The scripts will be looked by the admins before being ran but I want to prevent disasters if an exploit is not seen.

The client should only be able to use the functions defined by an API. My strategy was to create use `vm` to create a new context with only access to the `api`.

```
var vm = require('vm');

var v = 0; //incremetable via API

var api = {
    incr:function(){
        v++;
    }
}

var userCode =
`(function(api){
    api.incr();
    process.exit();     //ERROR: process is undefined
 })`;

vm.runInNewContext(userCode)(api);

console.log(v);
```

---

In theory, it looks fine. However, it turns out that you can still crash the server via

`api.incr.constructor("return this")().process.exit(1)`

---

How could I offer an API (aka capacity of the script to alter the main context) without compromising my server?

Something similar to `iframe` in the browser.

Comment: Bind all the functions to a this of the var `api`

Comment: This is a *very* complicated task due to the nature of JavaScript. I believe it can be done, but you must be extremely careful to avoid leaking objects cross-VM, and I've never seen anyone else implement this safely. Other kinds of attacks are also still possible, like consuming all the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a function's `this` by using the `.bind`. For example:

```
var api = {
   incr: (function() {
       return v++;
   }).bind(api)
}
```

Please note that this isn't throughly tested. **There are probably still ways to subvert such a method, but this will prevent some attacks. Generally, it's a bad idea to run user code on your server in the first place, VM or no** I'm actually quite surprised that Node allowed such a pitfall. It might be a good idea to post a bug report about it.

Comment: The idea is good but that won't be enough. I added `api.incr.constructor = null; api.incr.bind(null);` and it seems to do the job.

Comment: About running client code, it's more like having a github project and accepting contributions from others. This is equivalent to running user code after approval.

Comment: I hope you have success in your project. Good luck! :)

Comment: The function being called by `incr.constructor("return this;")` is the constructor of the function (ie. global Function constructor). Binding incr has no effect on that.

Comment: @harmic Like a said, untested. I'm just typing this in my phone

Comment: This topic is really rather difficult, and this proposed solution is *not* enough for untrusted code. Also, VM is used by Node's module systems, it's not a security error on their part if it is misused.

Comment: It also turns out you can just do `api.incr.toString.constructor` or other variant.